# javascript object : current or method?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("x");
```

This is the HTML:

```
<p id="x">text</p>
```

This is the next javascript:

```
x.innerHTML = "newtext"
alert(x.innerHTML)
```

So what will happen? Will x

> Save information when using `var x = document.getElementById("x")` and variable `x` will change but not HTML `<p>` with id `x`?

Comment: `x = document.getElementById("x")` will not change any HTML, but just assign a reference to an element.

Comment: Why the downvotes on this question? Seems like a legit question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since x is a reference to the DOM element, it'd modify the innerHTML of id - x.

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/j3ny5/)

```
var x = document.getElementById("x");
x.innerHTML = "newtext";
alert(x.innerHTML); //same as the below alert
alert (document.getElementById("x").innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `var x` that is referring to `<p> element` will change the `HTML of <p> element`.

```
var x = document.getElementById("x");
x.innerHTML = "newtext"
alert(x.innerHTML); //return "newtext"

var y = document.getElementById("x");
alert(y.innerHTML); //returns "newtext"
```

Changing the `innerHTML`property of `<p> element` using javascript has actually changed the `HTML`of `<p> element`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable x will still keep a reference to the DOM element with id "x" and the DOM element's innerHTML will change. So if you do like this afterwards

```
var content = x.innerHTML
```

then will content contain "newtext", but if you do like this afterwards

```
x.innerHTML = "new newtext"
```

then will `content` still contain "newtext" but then content of x will have changed. The variable `x` will still be a reference to the same DOM element.